# Connecting one android device with another android device through bluetooth to access phonebook, play music and manage calls

Tags: android, bluetooth, contacts, connectivity

I want to make an app which will connect from one android device to another through bluetooth. I want to access my phonebook, play music and manage calls.
I have searched for it alot but not getting much information about it. Also, I have searched for PBAP but didn't got much help in android.

I have also searched for IVI(In- Vehicle Infotainment) but not getting reference code for it.

Is there any other way to implement it?? or If you have any reference so do answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if Android has PBAP API at all but you can always implement it. You need the following services:

1. PBAP to work with PhoneBook.
2. AVRCP to work with Player.
3. HFP to work with calls.

PBAP is OBEX based profile, so you need the OBEX specification first. The you can download [PBAP spec](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj75o6IopLcAhUDiSwKHZonAWcQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bluetooth.org%2Fdocman%2Fhandlers%2Fdownloaddoc.ashx%3Fdoc_id%3D230887&usg=AOvVaw10fM44cctJx-GnT3sZ6q18).
AVRCP is L2CAP service.
AFAIR Android has HFP API.

Comment: do you have any reference code for implement PBAP on android?

Comment: Google does the things: [third link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/bluetooth/+/lollipop-dev/src/android/bluetooth/client/pbap/BluetoothPbapClient.java)

Comment: how about IVI in android? can we do it with IVI too?

Comment: I have tried implementing it but its not working. can you help me out?

Comment: What is IVI? Sure I can help. Ping me by skype (mike.petrichenko) and I'll try to help.